# C# ushort[] to string conversion; is this possible?

Tags: c#, string, ushort

I have a very painful library which, at the moment, is accepting a C# string as a way to get arrays of data; apparently, this makes marshalling for pinvokes easier.

So how do I make a ushort array into a string by bytes?  I've tried:

```
int i;
String theOutData = "";
ushort[] theImageData = inImageData.DataArray;
 //this is as slow like molasses in January
 for (i = 0; i < theImageData.Length; i++) {
     byte[] theBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(theImageData[i]);
     theOutData += String.Format("{0:d}{1:d}", theBytes[0], theBytes[1]);
 }
```

I can do it this way, but it doesn't finish in anything remotely close to a sane amount of time.

What should I do here?  Go unsafe?  Go through some kind of IntPtr intermediate?

If it were a char* in C++, this would be significantly easier...

edit: the function call is

```
DataElement.SetByteValue(string inArray, VL Length);
```

where VL is a 'Value Length', a DICOM type, and the function itself is generated as a wrapper to a C++ library by SWIG.  It seems that the representation chosen is string, because that can cross managed/unmanaged boundaries relatively easily, but throughout the C++ code in the project (this is GDCM), the char* is simply used as a byte buffer.  So, when you want to set your image buffer pointer, in C++ it's fairly simple, but in C#, I'm stuck with this weird problem.

This is hackeration, and I know that probably the best thing is to make the SWIG library work right.  I really don't know how to do that, and would rather a quick workaround on the C# side, if such exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

P/Invoke can actually handle what you're after most of the time using StringBuilder to create writable buffers, for example see [pinvoke.net on GetWindowText and related functions](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=GetWindowText).

However, that aside, with data as ushort, I assume that it is encoded in UTF-16LE. If that is the case you can use Encoding.Unicode.GetString(), but that will exepect a byte array rather than a ushort array. To turn your ushorts into bytes, you can allocate a separate byte array and use Buffer.BlockCopy, something like this:

```
ushort[] data = new ushort[10];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    data[i] = (char) ('A' + i);

string asString;
byte[] asBytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(ushort)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, asBytes, 0, asBytes.Length);
asString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(asBytes);
```

However, if unsafe code is OK, you have another option. Get the start of the array as a ushort*, and hard-cast it to char*, and then pass it to the string constructor, like so:

```
string asString;
unsafe
{
    fixed (ushort *dataPtr = &data[0])
        asString = new string((char *) dataPtr, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: that got it!  Thanks!  (the first part appears to be fast enough, even with the extra copy).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is switch from using a string to a stringBuilder it will help performance tremendously.

If you are willing to use unsafe code you can use pointers and implement the your c# code just like your c++.  Or you could write a small c++\cli dll that implements this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.aspx) class:

```
ushort[] theImageData = inImageData.DataArray;

byte[] buf = new byte[Buffer.ByteLength(theImageData)]; // 2 bytes per short
Buffer.BlockCopy(theImageData, 0, buf, 0, Buffer.ByteLength(theImageData));

string theOutData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, this has been fixed in later revision (gdcm 2.0.10). Look here:

http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/

-> http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=GDCM_Release_2.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this much, but it seems to work given the following assumptions:

**1.**  Each ushort is an ASCII char between 0 and 127

**2.**  (Ok, I guess there is just one assumption)

```
        ushort[] data = inData; // The ushort array source

        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[data.Length];  // Assumption - only need one byte per ushort

        int i = 0;
        foreach(ushort x in data) {
            byte[] tmp = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
            bytes[i++] = tmp[0];
            // Note: not using tmp[1] as all characters in 0 < x < 127 use one byte.
        }

        String str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but it's all I could come up with quickly.

Comment: sorry, the ushorts are across the entire dynamic range, 0 to 65535.

Comment: So I misunderstood the earlier comment about 8-bit chars?  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid unnecessary copying this way :

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string ConvertToString(this ushort[] uSpan)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(ushort) * uSpan.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < uSpan.Length; i++)
        {
            Unsafe.As<byte, ushort>(ref bytes[i * 2]) = uSpan[i];
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Unsafe` isn't available in .NET Framework 4, but it's quite easy to emulate it with bitwise operations like `bytes[size] = (byte)(uSpan[i] & 0xFF)` and `bytes[size + 1] = (byte)((uSpan[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8)`. And the original buffer is still copied to a temporary one this way.